# Did 15 doctors save a woman who had a heart attack on a plane?

Tags: cardiology

A image posted recently on 8fact [claimed](https://www.facebook.com/8fact/photos/a.121125554748254.1073741828.120709694789840/371872963006844/?type=1&theater) that:

> A woman had a heart attack on plane, when the stewardess asked if there was a doctor on board, 15 stood up, they were on their way to a cardiology conference.

[image]

Is the following story true?

Comment: Note that having a bunch of cardiologists around when having a heart attack is probably less beneficial than having a single ER doctor.

Comment: @Davor: I agree. While they argue against each other on how to treat the patient, she passes away :p

Comment: Reminds me of chain emails, reviving ancient news and recycling it as new.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

***Yes***, if BBC news is to be trusted.

[Gran's heart attack on jet with medics](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/uk_news/england/merseyside/3359149.stm)

> When the stewardess put out the call: "Is there a doctor on the plane", 15 cardiologists stood up to help 67-year-old Dorothy Fletcher.
>
> The doctors were en route to Orlando for a heart conference.

Comment: google search for "cardiology conference 15 doctors plane" gave this as the first link
http://www.medicalnewstoday.com/releases/5118.php
the name got the BBC article